# Use Angular Material mat-icon with custom svg icon in angular standalone library

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library, mat-icon

I'm creating this angular library for a project, and inside it, i'm utilizing @angular/material mat-icon component. There is some custom svg files included as assets of library, and i want to register then with `MatIconRegistry.addSvgIconSetInNamespace(path/to/assets/folter)`, and i do this, but i'm receiving the following error on runtime:

```
ERROR Error: Error retrieving icon XXX! Unable to find icon with the name "XXX"
```

I can't help it but to think that the problem is the url passed to `addSvgIconSetInNamespace`.
I'm building the library with ng-packagr and including de svg folder in the final dist folder. My dist folder structure is like this:

```
dist/lib
  \+--assets
    \+--svgs
  \+--modules
    \+--icon.module.ts
```

And in icon.module is where i need to register the icons present in assets folder. Someone knows how to fix it? Tells if this is a problem in register or runtime reference?

I tried to register in the following ways:
`addSvgIconSetInNamespace('@lib/assets/svgs/some.svg')`
`addSvgIconSetInNamespace('../assets/svgs/some.svg')`
`addSvgIconSetInNamespace('/assets/svgs/some.svg')`

But none of then worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried to set icon retrieval up as a service as described [here](https://dev.to/elasticrash/using-custom-made-svg-icons-through-the-angular-material-library-2pif)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).